# Using Javadoc to generate HTML with a left navigation bar

Tags: android, android-studio, javadoc

[p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfldv.png)

[p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcEyw.png)

The first image is the effect I want to generate, and the second image is the effect I generated using Javadoc directly in JDK11. How can I generate an effect like figure 1?

Answer (score 0):

For Javadoc 11, you can use the `--frames` option to get a "Frames" link in the top navigation bar. When clicking on that link, the documentation will be presented in the desired way.

Note, `--frames` has been removed in Javadoc 13. I.e. as of version 13, Javadoc is no longer able to create HTML frames.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, which solved my question.